# Large scale pivot table in Python

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, bigdata

I have 100-300Go data under csv format(numerical + unicode text) and needs to do regular Pivot Table jobs on this. After googling/StackOverflow-ing, could not find satisfactory answer (only partial).
 Wondering which solution is the fastest for single machine  (64Go RAM):

1) Convert and Insert into PostGres and proces all in PostGres DB through SQL ?
   (or MySQL....)

2) Load csv in chunk in Pandas and process one by one manually ?

3) Load csv + convert to HDF and process the HDF by chunk ?

4) Other solution.

Answer (score 0):

For working on a single machine, PostgreSQL may be the best fit from the 3 options you list.

To keep memory usage in check you can use [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html) and handle the data by chunks.

Comment: Any real experience on Pivot table on it ?

Comment: yeah, I've used those 3 tools to build pivot tables as well as olap cubes before. At the range of a few 100 Gb's postgreSQL works well as long as one partitions data so that it can work in memory and avoid using SWAP.

Comment: What if your pivot table has 2000 columns? How do you pivot using a relational database because the limit is 1024 columns for many of them

Comment: You should post that on a new question  @user798719

Answer (score 0):

The questioner must have solve the problem , for others whom might land upon this question , my answer might help.
Try this solution (convert it as per your dataset) , I tried on 50-80 GB it worked adding numpy will improve the performance.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime 

print("1 Load rec =", datetime.now())
df6 = pd.read_csv('sampleDataframeFlux/sampleDataframeFlux.csv',low_memory=False, memory_map=True,engine='c',na_filter=False,index_col=False,usecols=["time", "Label","Server","value"])
print("shape",df6.shape)
   
print("2 Create dataframe =",datetime.now())
df6["Label"]=df6["Server"]+"|"+df6["Label"]
df6.drop(['Server'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    
print("3 Time trim =", datetime.now())
df6['time']=df6['time']//1000000000
print("shape",df6.shape)
  
print("4 Round Epoch to nearest multiple of 5 =", datetime.now())
df6['time']=5*round(df6['time']/5)
print("shape",df6.shape)
  
print("5 Pivot dataframe=", datetime.now())
df6=df6.pivot_table(index='time', columns=["Label"],values="value",fill_value=0)
print("shape",df6.shape)

print("6 Epoch to UTC =", datetime.now())
df6.index=pd.to_datetime(df6.index, unit='s')
    
print("7 Convert to type category to reduce memory =", datetime.now())
df6=df6.astype('category')
print("shape",df6.shape)
   
print("8 Start to write to a file  =", datetime.now())
df6.to_csv('file_11.csv', header=True, chunksize=500000)
print("9 Finish =", datetime.now())
```